Network Delays with Time Clock in 2 locations but not others
We have been troubleshooting this issue for 4 months now and need some ideas at this point.
Issue: ADP Time clock devices at 2 of 4 locations are having delays stating "Waiting for server" between 5 seconds to several minutes causing delays in employee clock-ins for the day and clock-outs for lunch and end of shift.
Summary: We have 4 locations, we'll call A, B, C and D. Locations A and B have the issue, locations C and D do not. All locations have time clocks for employees to punch in and out of (purchased from ADP, InTouch 9000 devices). The time clock devices reach out to 2 WAN IP's of ADP's servers over 443.
Similarities:

All locations have Sophos Firewalls running the same firmware, Site-to-Site connectivity
All locations have Dell Switches connected to the Sophos firewall

Setup
Location A has 3 time clock devices, all having the issue:
Sophos Firewall <-> N1548P Dell switch ('Server Switch' firmware v 6.8.1.5 and 1 Timeclock patched in to this switch) <-> N1548P Dell switch ('Office Switch' firmware v 6.8.1.5 and 1 Timeclock patched in to this switch) <-> N1524P Dell switch ('Shed Switch' firmware v 6.8.1.5 and 1 Timeclock patched in to this switch)
To reiterate, the Shed switch is connected to the Office switch, which is connected to the Server switch, which is connected to the firewall. Each of these switches all have the same firmware, and 1 timeclock patched in.
Location B has 1 time clock device having the issue:
Sophos Firewall <-> N1108EP-ON Dell switch (switch firmware v 6.8.1.5 and 1 Timeclock patched in to this switch)
Locations C and D have 1 time clock at each site. The switches they are plugged into are a Dell N1548P and a Dell N2024P. The N1548P is running firmware 6.8.1.5, and the N2024P is running firmware 6.7.1.4.
Here is what I've gathered so far:

The issue appeared to have started at the same time (not 100% sure though) for the 2 sites and the 4 devices, but the issue never happened at the other 2 sites. The issue was supposedly started in March.
All Sophos firewalls are running the same firmware, SFOS 20.0.0 GA-Build222 at the moment. With the issue starting around March, and the last firewall update performed was back in December or January, I was wondering if the update was delayed in causing issues (maybe Sophos firewalls don't play nice natively with Dell switches all the time). A firmware update for the Dell switches was released recently, so when pushed, all of a sudden, the issue went away for 2 weeks. Then, our engineers had to push a firewall update to SFOS 20.0.0.1, and suddenly they started reporting the issue was back. We did a reversion on the firewalls to see if this was indeed a bug, and now it's back to SFOS 20.0.0 and the issue persists. Maybe we weren't getting good data from the on-site team during the time it was 'working'.
The switches at one site have the same firmware and models as Location A, so I'm thinking it's not model or firmware specific at this point.
I've run 2 different packet captures, one from the firewall and one doing port mirroring on the Server switch at Location A to our probe. The firewall's findings show the message "Could not associate packet to any connection" and according to Sophos support, it means something downstream caused a delay in the packet to be sent up. The packet capture from the mirrored port shows a lot of resets and retransmissions from the time clock device to the switch.
We were hoping it was a device issue, but all 4 devices going down at the same time seemed too big a coincidence to be device or even cable issue. We had ADP replace one of the time clocks as well, to no avail. Same issue kept occurring.

My next steps:

On-Site resource to directly connect time clock device to Sophos firewall to see if the issue persists

Other than that, I'm curious what else we should troubleshoot here or other packet captures to try and test with.

You didn’t mention anything about how the sites are connected to each other. You might be having WAN issues.

Where's the server the clocks are supposed to talk to? If this has to go across the firewall and the internet, there's your problem.

I'll edit my post to explain more. They have site-to-site connectivity, however the time clocks check into ADP's servers over HTTPS port 443. 2 IP's. I ran packet monitor on those IP's and found the time clocks showing the "Could not associate packet to any connection" Deny's. This is where I called Sophos thinking it was the firewall, to which they stated this simply is the packet timeout as if it's not making it in time from the time clock device to the firewall.

Thank you all! Update: After our on-site resource directly connected a time clock to the firewall and we tested with Sophos support, the issue persisted. Sophos has an internal ticket they are working through now and we are waiting to hear back.

To anyone seeing this. We plugged the time clock directly to the ISP's router. No issue. We plugged it directly to the Sophos firewall, and the issue occurred. After much testing, Sophos acknowledged this as a firmware bug in their latest v20 firewall. Bug is with IPS and the time clock devices.

Simply trace the packets coming from the clocks and the ones going into the firewall (or out to WAN). If there's a difference, you're losing those packets inside your network.
Most likely though, they're lost on the WAN side, so you'd need to talk to your ISP. Running traceroutes or pathpings towards the server for extended periods might help you with documenting the problem for them.
